# Can submit button clicked twice by user and script?

Tags: javascript

I've a timer set which will click a submit button automatically.

User can also press it.

**Can both be triggered at the same time?**

I can disable the button after click but if user clicks it and I disable it, it seems calling `$("#btn").click()` will still work.

I've googled this but could not find question like this.

**Context**: To prevent session expire, I want to submit a form programmatically after  5 minutes of a booking site which is heavily loaded. When I do could the user too by chance press the submit button?

**Code**

```
setTimeout(function (){ $("#btn").click()},  5*60000); //click after 5 minutes
```

//this will cause page to reload

Comment: it shouldn't - please show more context!

Comment: @Daniel I've updated it.

Comment: They cannot be triggered at the same time but you can of cource click it twice if you approach things you do it now. I'm really curious about the usecase though. It seems wrong in the first place.

Comment: @DanielA.White probably wanted to say to post your code here or on jsfiddle which will be better

Answer (score 2):

> Can both be triggered at the same time?

Yes, disabling and triggering are two different things.

When you disable a button, that will **only prevent the user** from triggering a click by pressing the button. However, programmatic click triggers will **still** execute all related events.

To prevent subsequent click handler executions, the easiest path would be to use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) like

```
$(document).one('click', '#btn', function(){...});
```

This will `undbind` the `click` event after it has been executed at most **once**.

Comment: It does not matter since the page will reload after click.

Comment: @user5858, it seems Im misunderstanding the problem. I understoody that you do not want to have a click handler executed twice by chance that the user clicked and $(btn).click() was called also. What is the problem then?